# Date type null value in dataframe not storing in cassandra

Tags: date, apache-spark, dataframe, cassandra

I am working in Apache Spark 1.6.0. I have a dataframe of 280 columns in which some of the columns are of type timestamp. A few values of the timestamp field are null. When I'm trying to write the same dataframe to cassandra, I'm getting an IllegalArgumentException.

The column looks like -

```
+------------------------+
|                LoginDate|
+-------------------------+
|                     null|
|     2014-06-25T12:27:...|
|     2014-06-25T12:27:...|
|                     null|
|     2014-06-25T12:27:...|
|     2014-06-25T12:27:...|
|                     null|
|                     null|
|     2014-06-25T12:27:...|
|     2014-06-25T12:27:...|
+-------------------------+
```

When I'm trying to save the whole dataframe to cassandra, it comes up the error -

```
05:39:22 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 106.0 (TID 5136,): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid date: 
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TimestampParser$.parse(TimestampParser.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$DateConverter$$anonfun$convertPF$13.applyOrElse(TypeConverter.scala:323)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:43)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$DateConverter$.com$datastax$spark$connector$types$NullableTypeConverter$$super$convert(TypeConverter.scala:313)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.NullableTypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$DateConverter$.convert(TypeConverter.scala:313)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$OptionToNullConverter$$anonfun$convertPF$31.applyOrElse(TypeConverter.scala:812)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:43)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$OptionToNullConverter.com$datastax$spark$connector$types$NullableTypeConverter$$super$convert(TypeConverter.scala:795)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.NullableTypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$OptionToNullConverter.convert(TypeConverter.scala:795)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.SqlRowWriter$$anonfun$readColumnValues$1.apply$mcVI$sp(SqlRowWriter.scala:26)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.SqlRowWriter.readColumnValues(SqlRowWriter.scala:24)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.SqlRowWriter.readColumnValues(SqlRowWriter.scala:12)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.BoundStatementBuilder.bind(BoundStatementBuilder.scala:100)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.next(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:106)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.next(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:157)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:134)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:139)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:134)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The type of the respective field in cassandra is of timestamp type.

Anyone can help to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following parameter to your spark Cassandra connection settings

> spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls=true

It will ignore the NULL values in the input and also has benefit of avoiding creation of a corresponding tombstone column in Cassandra.

Comment: Nephilim: Is there anymore clarification required in the answer provided? If the answer resolves your issue, please accept the answer (the tick mark)